# Thinking Sphinx OR on multiple columns within scope

Tags: ruby, thinking-sphinx, named-scopes

I need a way of conditioning a scope so that it checks if a value exists in one of three columns. This is my not code, I have just been told to edit it so it's hard to understand.

So, my condition in MYSQL would be:

```
WHERE `sub_client_1_id` = 53 OR `sub_client_2_id` = 53 OR `sub_client_3_id` = 53
```

I tried the following:

```
sphinx_scope(:by_sub_client){ |id| {:condition => "`sub_client_1_id` = #{id} OR `sub_client_2_id` = #{id} OR `sub_client_3_id` = #{id}" }}
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: why not use the `where` method e.g. `where("sub_client_1_id = :id OR sub_client_2_id = :id OR sub_client_3_id = :id", id: id)`

Comment: Which version of Thinking Sphinx are you using? And are these three columns attributes in your Sphinx index definition?